# How would you translate "one minute of this film is two minutes too much"?

Tags: translation

## Background

I am from Hong Kong (so I understand spoken Cantonese, spoken Mandarin, spoken English, written Chinese, and written English) but I am having a hard time translating that.

---

I would appreciate any help to translate that line while retaining the funniness.

Comment: @Downvoter: How can I improve this question?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but people like to see "homework" - attempted tries - possible solutions; seeing as you speak Chinese this shouldn't be a big problem. Show what you tried and why it does or doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Base on the context, it is a negative remark toward a particularly bad film.

Logically speaking,  if you watch one minutes of a film, even every second is horrible, the worst you can say is: " Watching one minute of this film is one minute too long." Meaning watching any of it is a waste of time.

However, all languages use exaggerated expressions. For example, "度日如年" ( a day feel like a year) --  It is quite a similar idea to the quote in the question, just not that extreme, ( " it is so boring, watching one minute feel like two."   * *As exaggeration goes, it is quite minor*

Using literal translation might not feel right. Since the main point of the sentence is to express " how unbearable a film is to the viewers" there's some suggestions:

看這部電影簡直度日如年 ( Watch this film make a day feel like a year)

這部電影貼錢也不值得看 ( This film is not worth watching even if they pay people to see it)

這部電影簡直浪費觀眾的青春 ( This film really is wasting viewers' youth) * *Great exaggeration*

Or use a funny Cantonese phrase 呢部戲睇過都要洗眼 ( you have to wash your eyes after you have seen this film)